# Deforming contour into the real axis.

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-integration

Need to prove $\displaystyle\int_\Gamma e^{-z^2}dz=\int_{-\infty}^\infty e^{-x^2}dx=\pi^{1/2}$ for the contour $\Gamma=\{Im(z)=a\}$.

Set $z= x+iy$ for $x,y \in \mathbb{R}$, then we have $$\int_\Gamma e^{-z^2}dz=e^{a^2}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}e^{-x^2}e^{-2xa i}dx$$

How to proceed after this? First, I tried to convert $e^{-2xai}$ to a trigonometric function and solve it. But it didn't work.

Comment: The elusive $\Gamma$ contour …

Comment: What is your contour? What is your $a$?

Comment: @MathFail Sorry for the confusion. I have edited the question.

Comment: Hint: Differentiate the $x$ integral with respect to $a$, then integrate by parts.

Comment: The OP might want a pure contour integral way?

Comment: I suppose for a pure contour integral way, make a box-shaped contour with one pair of sides on $\Gamma$ and the real axis and the other pair of sides at $\mathrm{Re}[z]=\pm k$, then take the limit as $k\rightarrow \infty$.